# Using the Raspberry Pi with a Touchscreen Monitor

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

I want to buy a big touchscreen monitor for my Raspberry Pi. I'm using Debian Wheezy.
I did some research and found the [Iiyama T2236MSC-B1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GCBQ2PI).
But i dont know if it will work with my Raspberry Pi.
I would be glad if you let me know if you got this or a similar Touchscreen working.
Or if you (somehow) know that it will work or not.
Other monitor suggestions or tutorials are appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i bought this Monitor and i connected it to my Raspberry via HDMI and USB.
And it just worked.